# How use rsync to copy the content of one directory and put in multiple direcotries?

Tags: command-line, rsync

I have a directory let's name it "A". And I want to copy its contents to directory "B" and "C". But the problem is that I don't want to pull all the contents, say "A" has 3 directories, and I want to put 2 of them in "B" and one in "C". I know I can do it easily by running rsync twice. But I was wondering if there's a way to do it in a single command. So far, I've tried this:

command 1:

```
rsync -vrF --progress A/** B/ --exclude='*.json'
```

command 2:

```
rsync -vrF --progress A/xyz.json C/'
```

thanks

Comment: is it because you don't want to type the commands out twice or because there are a tedious amounts of directories you have to do this with? I cant see it being worthwhile trying to figure out a solution for the former... in that case you could just put both commands on one line `rsync -vrF --progress A/** B/ --exclude='*.json'
; rsync -vrF --progress A/xyz.json C/'` ... in the latter case i think you would have to explain if the example you have there is always going to be expected format(and other specifics) for someone to provide an appropriate solution

Comment: @WU-TANG hmm. Actually, I am doing this to move artifacts from the build directory during my deployment process. The build system pukes everything in a single directory, then it's up to the deployment system to put each file in the right place so that everything works as expected. I didn't want to add multiple commands for this task. I'm doing as you mentioned in the comment for now. but I thought rsync could do this in a single command.

Comment: It will be good to add your real problem, X to the actual question instead of asking about problem Y, what you think is the solution to your problem. XY problems (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) can be difficult to solve.